# Azure Devops pipelines free tier

Tags: azure-devops

The documentation for Azure Devops free tier says '1800 minutes/month, 1 parallel job'.  However, there also seems to be various documents that say '1 free pipeline'. I have numerous small projects, each requiring their own pipeline. I can stay under the 1800 minutes between all pipelines, but I just need to confirm that I can have any number of free pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation for Azure Devops free tier says '1800 minutes/month, 1 parallel job'. However, there also seems to be various documents that say '1 free pipeline'.

First of all, there is no limit to the number of pipelines, and you can create many, many pipelines whether you set up billing or not.

But if you use free tier, you only have one parallel job. For example, if you have 2 pipelines and you run them, the pipelines will queue up and the second pipeline will run only after the first pipe has run.

So,

> I can stay under the 1800 minutes between all pipelines, but I just need to confirm that I can have any number of free pipelines.

You can have many pipelines, but you can't run them all at once. They can only run one after another.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I understand the parallel job part (makes sense), I just wasn't sure if they could be split over many pipelines.